# golang way to do inheritance, the workaround

Tags: inheritance, go

I understand golang does not support inheritance, but what is the right way to do in go for the following?

```
type CommonStruct struct{
  ID string
}

type StructA struct{
  CommonStruct
  FieldA string
}

type StructB struct{
  CommonStruct
  FieldB string
}

func (s *CommonStruct) enrich(){
  s.ID = IDGenerator()
}
```

how I can reuse the code in enrich for all other "sub struct" if the following function?

```
func doSomthing(s *CommoStruct){
  s.enrich()
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an interface:

```
type MyInterface interface {
    enrich()
}

func doSomthing(s MyInterface){
  s.enrich()
}
```

Any struct that has each of the functions or methods of an interface defined is considered an instance of said interface.  You could now pass anything with a `CommonStruct` to `doSomething()`, since `CommonStruct` defined `enrich()`.  If you want to override `enrich()` for a particular struct, simply define `enrich()` for that struct.  For example:

```
type CommonStruct struct{
  ID string
}

type StructA struct{
  *CommonStruct
}

type StructB struct{
  *CommonStruct
}

type MyInterface interface {
    enrich()
}

func doSomething(obj MyInterface) {
    obj.enrich()
}

func (this *CommonStruct) enrich() {
    fmt.Println("Common")
}

func (this *StructB) enrich() {
    fmt.Println("Not Common")
}

func main() {
    myA := &StructA{}
    myB := &StructB{}
    doSomething(myA)
    doSomething(myB)
}
```

Prints:

> Common
>   Not Common

[Test it here!](http://play.golang.org/p/TWJVUPer-g).

Comment: thansk Steve, indeed it is working already, but I was not expressing my idea properly and I have edited the post, could you please take a look again? thanks

Comment: thanks Steve again, but does it mean I have to have separate impl on enrich for each 'sub struct'? but what if enrich will always doing the same thing (assigning ID etc) and would be good if I can reuse it for all 'sub struct'

Comment: Now wondering why doing also `myA.ID = "A"` and  `myB.ID = "B"` in `main()` crashes it... I.e. how to init a common element, need to add another shared method?